# Using toast for form success and error input

Tags: desktop-application, notification, validation

is it natural to use toast notification for a success and error on form validation? I know android and google mail uses this on their application, but I cannot verify why this is the best solution when displaying success and errors when validating. Thanks!!

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is that manage screen UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't say whether or not this is the best solution, but here are some advantages of toasts over other interface notifications:

- Toasts provide a consistent location for important messages to display.
- Toasts are versatile and typically don't require contextual placement, as they can be displayed over any existing interface elements.
- Toast animations draw user attention.

Your interface is clean, the toast is well-placed, and you have a timeout and give the user the option to remove it. I think your solution both is elegant and functional (even if there's a grammatical error).